# Publish bot to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

When I published my bot to Azure from Visual Studio and trying it on the web chat, it says **can't send the message**. Running the bot locally everything works just fine.

The emulator reports HTTP 500 error when trying to chat with the endpoint on azure.

Comment: Welcome on stack overflow. Please provide a [minimum sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussions in the comment section, I've pulled your code from the repository you've provided. Different to what you were saying, it also crashes locally with HTTP 500 on start. Reading the logs gave me issues with `web.config`.

**This leads me to the following solution:**

Your codebase contains a `web.config` file which doesn't belong there. This is a .net core application and therefore should not rely on `web.config` and instead use [appsettings.json](https://zimmergren.net/using-appsettings-json-instead-of-web-config-in-net-core-projects/). When this `web.config` gets deployed, the runtime tries to load certain things and crashes with HTTP 500.

Not sure where this `web.config` comes from but I assume from previous deployments or some test of yours. 
I've send you a PR simply removing this `web.config` and deployed your bot to Azure.

**It works well:**

[image: Azure deployed]

Make sure you've selected **remove additional files at destination** when you publish it from Visual Studio after removing `web.config`. This way you're making sure that you not accidentally leave an orphaned `web.config` there.
[image: VS Studio publish settings]

Comment: Thank you, it works
I upvouted you but I got less than 15 reputation so it won't be displayed

Comment: Great! @PedroRodrigues . Please mark it as answer as well in addition to the upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While your question is missing detailed information's, I know from experience that most people forget to include a bot state when they deploy the bot on azure.

[Bot State Service retired](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/12/19/bot-state-service-will-soon-retired-march-31st-2018/) on March 31st, 2018. 
Therefore most samples on the web are missing state storage when running it on Azure giving you HTTP 500, while it will work locally.

For a solution see my recent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55460345/2715229) on stack overflow.

Comment: I use MemoryStorage in the bot, is it mandatory that I change that to the blob storage or cosmo db?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues no, memory storage is fine. Please check in your code to a github repo and share the link. I‘ll have a look then later.

Comment: I push my project to github, https://github.com/PedroR96/dialogBot.git, in development/localhost mode it works fine, but in azure it gives that error

Comment: @PedroRodrigues send you a PR that fixes the issue. In addition I've posted a second reply explaining your problem. Could you please upvote both of my answers as they are relevant and mark the second one as correct if it now works for you? thanks

Answer (score -1):

Http 500 error is a very general internal server error. You can add some exception handling logic and log it into Application Insights.

You can refer to the documents 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-trace-logs

Comment: I think this is not a good answer. You should have let him know in comment that he needs to provide a sample and give this as a hint and not as an answer.