# Microsoft Bot Framework - Call from Azure app service to external Web API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework

I had a Microsoft Bot Framework project that connect to Web API(that not hosted in azure). 
in local host everything was work fine. but when i was deployed the Bot to an Azure app service. it's seem that the call is failed(and the Bot not return any response).

this is my post request:

```
 public static string Post(List<ActionInputParams> data, string url)
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json;charset=utf-8";               

            try
            {
                var res = wc.UploadString(url, "POST", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
                return res;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "error " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

**my question:** there is a problem to call to external Web API from Azure app service? or i just missing something?

in the "log stream" i getting a 500 error:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>   The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Comment: "there is a problem to call to external Web API from Azure app service? or i just missing something?" : you are probably missing something ;-)

Comment: If it works local, but not in Azure, you can try using [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/) to help isolate the issue. Do you have all your async/await stuff in order?

Comment: Are you able to share the API endpoint?  Also, have you tried enabling remote debugging to see if you can get some more info on the error and it's occurrence?

Comment: HTTP 500 could be everything and maybe you're missleaded. Check my answers on HTTP 500 questions related to bot framework [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55591939/2715229) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55460345/2715229). 
If this doesn't help, please push your code to github and send me the link. I will have a look.